# Firebase firestore in flutter web

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i'm trying to get my data from firebase firestore to flutter web project. i do all steps carefully but when i test the getData() method i get just this

:**[2023-06-03T18:15:20.634Z]  @firebase/firestore:**

this is my method:

```
  Future<void> getData() async {

    FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    CollectionReference collection = firestore.collection('Users');


   QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await collection.get();


     for (DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot in querySnapshot.docs) {
       final data = docSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
  
  String? name = data['User'];
  print(name);
}
```

[image: and this a screenshot of firestore console and the document which i try to get it :]
so if there any problem inside the function getData() or else problem please tell me.

Thank you

Comment: Please update your question to include a screenshot from the Firestore console of a document that you expect this code to read and print. Make sure we can see all relevant parts in the screenshot, such as the path to the document, and the field that you're trying to print.

Comment: The field is called `user`, not `user/user`. So that'd be `String? name = data['user'];`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry for this mistake, i added it by wrong here, I updated my question, String? name=data['user];  give the same result

Comment: Now the code in your question capitalized `User` different than the field name in the document.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?